# Send mail from JSF page using beans

Tags: java, email, jsf, primefaces

i am creating a web application using jsf and primefaces, and my question is how to send an email through site's contact form (i've done this using php before, very easily, but never using jsf). I have created form on contact.xhtml page, as well as bean class to support that, and all that form should do is to send bean's data to a predefined mail (ie. gmail). I have also found several "tutorials" of how to send email using JavaMail, but nothing seems to work properly. The form itself, consists of name, email and message fields.

Can someone write how to do that, or give me a link. I would be very gratefull.

Do i need my site to be running on (online) server, or i can test it from localhost.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a SMTP server or at least the hostname, port number and the login details of your SMTP server? What Java EE server are you using? (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc). It's "easy" in PHP because lot of hosting servers are already preconfigured for that. You just have to call the `mail()` function. Or you just have to enter SMTP host config in some ini file. Tomcat doesn't supprort this preconfiguration (it only supports JSP/Servlet out box, not JavaMail, so you've to write the whole bunch of code yourself), but Glassfish for example supports it (JavaMail is namely part of Java EE web profile).

Comment: Please do note that this problem is not related to JSF in general. This is related to the target server and its configuration. Depending on that you could just utilize its JavaMail JNDI resource, or have to write a lot of boilerplate code yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In very short:

- make a `<h:commandButton action="#{yourBean.send}"`
- make a managed bean annotated with `@ManagedBean("yourBean")` that has a `send(..)` method
- get [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) and read its short "User guide"; get a working smtp server (commons-email depends on JavaMail, so get that on the classpath as well)
- in the send method use commons-email to send the email

(You should go through a JSF tutorial to see how to gather the form parameters)

Note that java is a bit more complex. "Send mail through JSF" isn't a particularly good question. It consists of two questions:

- how to have a form submitted with JSF (every tutorial explains that)
- how to send email in Java in general

Answer (score 2):

It is all about how to capture JSF output. My approach is just to call the JSF page via JAX-RS, capture output and put it into e-mail. Be carefull to make the page as simplest as possible (JSF likes to add a lot of JS code) , and set absolute URLs to resources.
Here is my code (simplified):

```
@Resource(name = "mail/mySession")
Session mailSession;

//make request, capture output
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String htmlBody = 
        client.target("http://localhost:8080/AppName/jsfpage.xhtml")
        .queryParam("id", 10) //we can add some params
        .request()
        .get(String.class);

//send email
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setFrom();
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("asd@asd.pl"));
message.setHeader("X-Mailer", "JavaMail");
message.setSubject("Subject here");
message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8"); //set captured html as content
message.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

On my practice SEAM Mail really helps in sending mail.

Here you can find a good tutorial on it:

[**Sending mail from JSF - Seam mail**](http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/04/sending-mail-from-jsf-seam-mail.html)